# How to merge two Cassandra cluster into one?

Tags: cassandra

I have two Cassandra clusters, cluster 1 has one keyspace called 'Keyspace1', and cluster 2 has one keyspace called 'Keyspace2'. I want to merge two cluster into one.

How can I do that?

Comment: How much data?  How many column families?

Answer (score 3):

If the cluster in which you are going to hold the data has sufficient space then one of the options could be to stream sstable's data and index files to that cluster using sstable-loader.

For more information see [Cassandra Bulk Loader](http://www.shareitexploreit.blogspot.in/2012/02/cassandra-bulk-loader.html)